# Why say Hashem is Jealous and Vengeful when we ask for Kindness?

Tags: shabbat-songs, kol-mikadesh

> משוך חסדך ליודעיך, אל קנוא ונוקם

We ask Hashem to give us kindness and then we say because you are a God of Jealousy and Vengeance. It would seem we should say he is full of kindness and not bring up Jealousy and anger at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harav Hakadosh R' Baruch Mmez"ibuz: Meshoch chasdecha (pour your kindness?) upon us, Yisrael, EVEN during those times when your are Kaneh Venokem (G' of Jealousy and Vengeance).

Comment: love that answer